# My device is not locking

Tags: lock-screens

My android device is 4.4.2 with root access.

Mode of Screen Lock is Password.

Earlier, the screen got locked with password.

Now, the screen time out in a specific time but its not getting locked with password.

Please let me know, what I need to do to fix it?

Regards

InTech

Comment: Is it a custom rom on phone?

Comment: No. Its Stock ROM only with Xposed Amplify, Xposed BootManager, Xposed Greenify, Xposed Privacy, Startup Manager & Busy Box.

Comment: Hm, well then, does it lock with password when it's locked for some time eg 10 minutes? Maybe you turned on lock phone after x minutes sleeping..?

Comment: No, only screen goes off in 10 min. without password lock.

Comment: Well you said password stopped apearing after changing screen timeout time. So try to change it back on that value. Also try setting screenlock to swipe or none and than back to password.

Comment: I did same. I see same issue with swipe also. Sometimes swipe lock appears and sometimes it doesn’t appear. After this, I removed root access from my device, reset my device & rooted my device. Then I tried these locks; Swipe, Pattern & Password. I see similar issue in all i.e. sometimes lock screen appears sometimes it doesn’t appear.

Comment: Well then it could be rom releated bug. Does it work fine wothout root on phone?

Comment: I didn’t check without root. Please let me know, what I need to do in both scenarios, if same issue without root or if no issue without root?

Comment: If error is still there without root, than only thing that you can try is flashing stock firmware. And if there isn't error when phone is not rooted than you should try different way to root the phone maybe something is screewed in rooting process

Comment: I checked. Without root, Locking Screen is working fine. After rooting, I see same problem again. There are many apps for rooting android but from beginning (for more than one year) I have been using Kingo Root. Also depending upon scenario, I removed root access, reset device and re-root device multiple times. And I never had any issue with Kingo Root. I don’t want to use any other app. Please help me to fix issues with Kingo Root. Also I does support android 4.4.2.

Comment: Just try with other app and see if it still make you troubles, just to be sure is app causes troubles or root itself. Root phone via flashing super SU from recovery, you should avoid 'one click root' apps

Comment: From beginning I have been using rooting with PC. I don’t prefer one click root or root without PC. For last one-two days, I have been performing similar tasks multiple times like reset device, rooting device, un-rooting device. Because of these tasks sometimes I am suspicious of risk of device hardware and ROM. Device hardware is MT6592 and device board is ht1_107a_iball_mjk.

Comment: I tried other apps like farmaroot, z4root, TunesGo Root etc (with PC and Without PC). In almost all cases, there are some issues/errors in rooting process. Also in some apps, language is not English that’s why I didn’t prefer to proceed. TunesGo Root is paid app. Only Kingo Root with PC and Kingo Root without PC can root my device successfully. But after rooting device, I see same issue i.e. screen lock issue.